# APP crashing on realme , oppo and oneplus Phones

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-spinner, crashlytics

Here are Crash details from Crashes and ANRs

com.$$$$$$.fieldforce.activity.ProvisioningScreenActivity.lambda$getAccountDetails$3$ProvisioningScreenActivity

- java.lang.NullPointerException

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource (ArrayAdapter.java:454)
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView (ArrayAdapter.java:502)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView (AppCompatSpinner.java:756)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getView (AppCompatSpinner.java:750)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.compatMeasureContentWidth (AppCompatSpinner.java:590)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.computeContentWidth (AppCompatSpinner.java:1026)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show (AppCompatSpinner.java:1053)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.showPopup (AppCompatSpinner.java:616)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick (AppCompatSpinner.java:460)
  at com.$$$$$$$.fieldforce.activity.ProvisioningScreenActivity.lambda$getAccountDetails$3$ProvisioningScreenActivity (ProvisioningScreenActivity.java:230)
  at com.$$$$$$$.fieldforce.activity.-$$Lambda$ProvisioningScreenActivity$YnrGP_9DLrME_v-i79em930emIg.onClick
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7558)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7534)
  at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:29652)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:240)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:351)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8355)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:584)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1013)
```

App is crashing on clicking the Model spinner.

[image: Form image]

I'm not able to fix it because its working fine on my Samsung

this is the function which causing the problem

```
public void getAccountDetails() {

    try {
        binding.tvModel.setOnClickListener(v -> binding.spModel.performClick());
        binding.spModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        inAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);
        inAnimation.setDuration(200);
        binding.progressLayout.progressOverlay.setAnimation(inAnimation);
        binding.progressLayout.progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AccountInfoRequest accountInfoRequest = new AccountInfoRequest();
        accountInfoRequest.setAuthkey(Constants.AUTH_KEY);
        accountInfoRequest.setAction(Constants.GET_ACCOUNT_DETAILS);
        accountInfoRequest.setCanId(strCanId);
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<AccountDetailsResponse> call = apiService.getAccountDetails(accountInfoRequest);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<AccountDetailsResponse>() {
            @Override
            `public void onResponse(Call<AccountDetailsResponse> call,  Response<AccountDetailsResponse> response)` {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    outAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
                    outAnimation.setDuration(200);
                    binding.progressLayout.progressOverlay.setAnimation(outAnimation);
                    binding.progressLayout.progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (response.body().getStatus().equals("Success")) {
                        try {
                            binding.setResponse(response.body().getResponse().data);
                            `if(response.body().getResponse().data.onuProfile!=null||response.body().getResponse().data.onuProfile.size()!=0) {`
                                `onuProfile = response.body().getResponse().getData().getOnuProfile();`
                            }
                            `if(response.body().getResponse().data.towerDetail!=null||response.body().getResponse().data.towerDetail.size()!=0) {`
                               ` strTowerId = response.body().getResponse().getData().getTowerDetail().get(0).getTowerId();`
                                `strSplitterId = response.body().getResponse().getData().getTowerDetail().get(0).getServingDB();`
                            }
                            modelName = new ArrayList<>();
                            modelId = new ArrayList<>();
                            modelName.add("Select Model Name");
                            for (AccountDetailsResponse.OnuProfile onuProfile : onuProfile)
                                modelName.add(onuProfile.getModelName());
                            for (AccountDetailsResponse.OnuProfile id : onuProfile)
                                modelId.add(id.getProfileName());
                            if(modelName!=null) {
                               ` ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProvisioningScreenActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, modelName);`
                                `adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`
                                binding.spModel.setAdapter(adapter1);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (response.body().getStatus().equals("Failure")) {
                        `Toast.makeText(ProvisioningScreenActivity.this, response.body().getResponse().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
                        nextScreen();
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AccountDetailsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                binding.progressLayout.progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.e("RetroError", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(parent.getId() == R.id.sp_model){
        binding.tvModel.setText(modelName.get(position));
        if (position != 0) strModel = "" + modelId.get(position - 1);
        else strModel = " ";
        binding.tvProfileName.setText(strModel);

    }
}
```

this screenshot of above code and line 230 is highlighted
[image: this screenshot of above code and line 230 is highlighted]

Comment: Have you check null inside the `modelName` array? It seems that there is null inside the array causing such problem.

Comment: e.g., `modelName` = {"Model A", "Model B", null, "Model C"}

Comment: yes one field is null in the API response that could be the issue.

Comment: You may give a try to drop the null record first. If the issue resolves, then handle the `null` data gracefully (e.g., drop it with log, replace it with other meaningful field or just drop it if it is not important).